# Eclipse Maven project to Dynamic Web Project layout

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am used to the layout provided by the Dynamic Web project in eclipse where you have all your Java code under the src folder, your JSP files, etc under the WebContent folder and the WEB-INF resides right under the WebContent folder. Also, the Output folder is hidden from the project tree. Maven has its own format which I find somewhat confusing, it creates its now target folder and source/main/java folder and some test folder under target...

Is there a way to create a Maven project and have it use the Dynamic Web project project tree layout?

I tried changing the Deployment Assembly entries to match that of the Dynamic web project and have also update the Java Build Path src and output to match the Dynamic Web project one but I get strange, cryptic unfriendly errors when I do a Run/Install. Can you provide me with details on how to go about doing this cleanly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to get used to using is the concept of `archetypes` in Maven.
The concept is like project templates ready for you to use that are automatically understood by Maven.

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

will get you an interactive listing of all the available `archetypes`

What you want to look for is `maven-archetype-webapp` this will give you a basic skeleton framework of what Maven is expecting a webapp to look like.

There are others that include support for different frameworks and what not.

```
mvn archetype:generate | grep webapp
```

will filter out all the choices that are webapp `archetypes`

Then it is a simple `mvn clean package` and you get an exploded dir and a `.war` in the `target` directory, you can even enable the Tomcat plugin to automatically deploy to Tomcat. Other J2EE servers are supported as well.

Then you use the Maven plugin for eclipse to load the project based on the `pom.xml` file.

[You could create your own non standard layout and get it working by manually configuring everything thing and create an `archetype`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) out of it but that kind of defeats the purpose of a single way of doing things with a tool like Maven.

Comment: Thank you for that. Is there a way to create a archetypes off of an existing one, like the maven-archetype-webapp one? and then modify it slightly so it matches the layout of the Dynamic Web project?

Comment: [Yes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) but I wouldn't recommend it, not when there is a perfectly good way of doing it already that *everyone* will be expecting that comes behind you.

Answer (score 1):

Using [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) 1.3+ and [m2e-wtp](http://eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/) 0.16.0+, you can just :

- create a new Dynamic Web project
- right-click on the project > Configure > Convert to Maven...
- Fill in the Maven coordinates of your project and finish

It'll mavenize your project, keeping the standard Eclipse project layout.

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E-WTP/New_and_Noteworthy/0.16#New_project_conversion_participants for more information

Comment: I swapped "Dynamic Web project" for Google eclipse plugin style "New Web Application Project". But get an error - "No persistence.xml file found in project". any ideas? see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695458/eclipse-how-to-fix-error-no-persistence-xml-file-found-in-project-jpa-issue