# Eclipse - How to fix error "No persistence.xml file found in project" JPA issue

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, gwt, persistence.xml

Error "No persistence.xml file found in project" in Eclipse.

Aim: Create a new project GWT+App engine+Maven

Steps to create this:

1. Google eclipse plugin: select "New Web Application Project".
2. set the name etc.
3. right-click on the project > Configure >
   Convert to Maven...
4. Fix jdoconfig.xml file: xsi has the wrong
   value. see
   [Validating jdoconfig with incorrect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042475/validating-jdoconfig-with-incorrect-url)

Then I get the above error.

The file exists at scr/META-INF/persistence.xml
and also war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
But is not being found.

Notes: I installed plugins m2e, m2e-wtp and google eclipse plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell eclipse to ignore: "No persistence.xml file found in project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287026/how-to-tell-eclipse-to-ignore-no-persistence-xml-file-found-in-project)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using eclipse.
Try right clicking the Project File -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path

Step 1: Add the folder META-INF to the build path

Step 2: Right click the Project File -> Maven -> Update Project

Comment: Steps that worked: 1. Add the folder META-INF to the build path. 2.  right clicking the Project File -> Maven -> Update Project.  ..... (I could then remove the folder META-INF from the build path and all was fine. But "Maven -> Update Project", on its own did not work, needed both steps.)

Comment: Is this one of those things one should not ask questions about with Eclipse? I mean: the META-INF/persistence.xml is in the buildpath but the "Maven -> Update Project" still does not remove the message. Or should persistence.xml really be in the root of the classpath?